# cut an array column in csv

Tags: linux, csv, database

I want to cut an array column in a CSV file. For example if you see the below CSV file

input.csv

```
1,2,"{1,2,3}",1

3,4,"{3,9,1}",2

8,9,"{10,12,30}",3
```

I want the output as

output.csv

```
1,2,3

3,9,1

10,12,30
```

I tried using `cut -d , -f 3 input.csv`
and `cut -d { -f 3 input.csv` but both did not work .Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you always want the last column and does the last column always have values enclosed in `"{}"`?

Comment: if above is true, try `sed 's/.*{\|}"//g' input.csv`

Comment: No It is not the last column.It is a column at the third position

Comment: `cut -d\" -f2 input.csv | tr -d [{}]`

Comment: cut -d , -f-2,5- input.csv | tr -d [}\"]

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` you can define multiple field delimiters with `-F'[]'`, so you can define both braces as delimiters and print the then second field:

```
awk -F'[{}]' '{print $2}' input.csv
1,2,3
3,9,1
10,12,30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input.csv
1,2,"{1,2,3}",1
3,4,"{3,9,1}",2
8,9,"{10,12,30}",3

$ sed -E 's/^([^,],){2}"\{([^}]+).*/\2/' input.csv
1,2,3
3,9,1
10,12,30
```

- some `sed` versions used `-r` instead of `-E` for extended regex
- `^([^,],){2}` first two columns
- `"\{` match `"{` in third column, not captured
- `([^}]+)` capture non`}` characters
- `.*` rest of line
- replace entire line with required string

With `grep` and `pcre`

```
$ grep -oP '^([^,],){2}"\{\K[^}]+' input.csv 
1,2,3
3,9,1
10,12,30
```