# cut an array column and join an another column to a csv file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file as

```
input.csv

1,2,3,"{1,2,3}",9,12
1,2,3,"{1,2,3}",9,12
1,2,3,"{1,2,3}",9,12
```

I needed to remove the array column from the above CSV file and get the output as

```
output.csv

1,2,3,9,12
1,2,3,9,12
1,2,3,9,12
```

So I tried

```
cut -d , -f4 -- complement input.csv > output.csv
```

But the above command gave the error

> The delimiter must be a single character

I also want to join the output.csv with another CSV file

```
column.csv
30
36
90
```

Then the result would look like

```
result.csv
1,2,3,9,12,30
1,2,3,9,12,36
1,2,3,9,12,90
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: So how is [that question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317639/19575) a duplicate and this question is not?

Answer (score 1):

with Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) starting from

```
1,2,3,"{1,2,3}",9,12
1,2,3,"{1,2,3}",9,12
1,2,3,"{1,2,3}",9,12
```

is very simple and you can run

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output cut -x -f 4 input.csv | paste -d , - column.csv
```

to obtain

```
1,2,3,9,12,30
1,2,3,9,12,36
1,2,3,9,12,90
```

With `cut -x -f 4` I remove the fourth column and with `paste` I add column.csv column

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle quoted delimiters, you should consider using a purpose-designed CSV parser - for example, the one from the perl Text::CSV module. For example,

```
paste -d, input.csv column.csv | perl -MText::CSV -ne '
  BEGIN {$csv = Text::CSV->new()}
  if ($csv->parse($_)) {
    @a = $csv->fields();
    splice(@a, 3, 1);
    print join(",", @a) . "\n";
  }'
1,2,3,9,12,30
1,2,3,9,12,36
1,2,3,9,12,90
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with 'awk'?

Comment: @joker21, yes possible but using a parser will be better and robust in the  long run... `paste -d, input.csv column.csv | awk -F',"{|}"' '{print $1 $3}'` or even `paste -d, input.csv column.csv | sed 's/,"{[^}]*}"//'`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use purpose-designed CSV parser as sugested by @steeldrive, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{split($0,a,"\""); print a[1] substr(a[3],2)}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Be aware that this will only work for the style provided  in the example.

**Explanation:**

Split the text every `"`

```
{split($0,a,"\"")
```

Print and remove the first `,` of the second column

```
print a[1] substr(a[3],2)
```