# remove an array column with different length

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I want to remove an array which does not have a fixed size.For example

```
file.csv

001,"Geography",TRUE,"{1,0,1,1}",1,"CHARLIE"
002,"History",FALSE,"{0,0,1,1}",0,"DAVID"
003,"Mathematics",TRUE,"{1,1,1,1}",1,"SAM"
```

The following array should be converted into the below format

```
file_edited.csv

001,"Geography",TRUE,1,"CHARLIE"
002,"History",FALSE,0,"DAVID"
003,"Mathematics",TRUE,1,"SAM"
```

How to do this in the command line.

Comment: does your input has only one of these array? or can there be multiple? also, this question is similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318446/cut-an-array-column-and-join-an-another-column-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are tons of different ways to accomplish this, I prefer `sed`:

```
sed 's/"{.*}",//'
```

On **GNU/Linux** (GNU `sed`), use:

```
sed 's/"{.*}",//' csv
001,"Geography",TRUE,1,"CHARLIE"
002,"History",FALSE,0,"DAVID"
003,"Mathematics",TRUE,1,"SAM"
```

**OS X** (BSD `sed`, note the `-E` flag):

```
sed -E 's/"{.*}",//' csv 
001,"Geography",TRUE,1,"CHARLIE"
002,"History",FALSE,0,"DAVID"
003,"Mathematics",TRUE,1,"SAM"
```

Comment: -r doesn't work in Linux.it shows as sed: -e expression #1,char 11:Invalid content of \{\

Comment: @rkr See my edit for both GNU and BSD `sed`

Comment: @ maulinglawns This works perfectly!!! Thanks

Comment: FYI, `-E` is supported by both `GNU` and `BSD` `sed`

Comment: Don't you need `g` at the end of your `sed` in case of multiple pattern occurences in the same line ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Python and its CSV module, for example the following single command:

```
python -c 'import sys,csv
w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    del row[3]
    w.writerow(row)' < file.csv > file_edited.csv
```

The magic happens on the second-to-last row in the command. In Python, arrays start at index 0, so `row[3]` is the fourth column; so, this one simply removes the fourth column on each record.

Alternatively, you can simply print columns 0, 1, 2, 4, and 5, using

```
python -c 'import sys,csv
w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    w.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[4], row[5]])' < file.csv > file_edited.csv
```